# iron:router not rendering template

Tags: javascript, templates, meteor, render, iron-router

I am working on meteor with the iron:router package.
My javascript file contains:

```
Router.route('/', function () {
  this.render('home');
}, {
  name: 'home'
});

Router.route('/hello', function () {
  this.render('hello');
});
```

My html file contains:

```
<head>
  <title>test</title>
</head>

<body>
  <h1>Welcome to Meteor!</h1>

</body>

<template name="hello">
  <button>Click Me</button>
  <p>You've pressed the button {{counter}} times.</p>
</template>

<template name="home">
  <h2>Home</h2>
  <p>You are on the home screen.</p>
</template>
```

Whatever I write (`localhost:3000/hello` or `localhost:3000/`) as specified in [the tutorial](https://github.com/iron-meteor/iron-router/blob/master/Guide.md), no matter what it will NOT render any template at all. It simply displays the header "Welcome to Meteor!" and that's it.

When I write any other non-declared address such as `localhost:3000/abc`, it shows me:

> Welcome to Meteor! Oops, looks like there's no route on the client or
>   the server for url: "http://localhost:3000/abc."

So it definitely is doing something right in the javascript file, since it recognizes the templates it should know, but still when writing the right address, it shows nothing.

I tried looking at other solutions, check that the package name was "iron:router" and not "iron-router", as well as other solutions, but nothing has worked. Please help me...

Edit: As requested, here is a repository of the project https://github.com/yokhen/test2

Comment: It doesn't even see iron:router package, cause it shows basic template (in `body` tags). Otherwise if it were routes problem you would see something like `Whooops, route for ... doesn't exist`. Where do you have your routes .js file? In lib directory?

Comment: @Sindis I just added extra info. My .js file is in the project folder

Comment: Leave only templates in your html file, delete body and head tags - what does it show now?

Comment: @Sindis yeah, tried that too, but no nothing shows up. I might give meteorBuzz's answer a try but it'll take me a few minutes, hopefully it works.

Comment: meteorBuzz answer is about layouts, I don't think it will make a difference - maybe create simple github repo with code you already did and we'll check it

Comment: @Sindis omg finally I did it. Github is such a pain https://github.com/yokhen/test2

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/90697/discussion-between-yokhen-and-sindis).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First of all I had to add EJSON package because iron:router didn't see it (although I was testing it on Windows, maybe that's why I had this issue)

`meteor add ejson` solved it

Your project directory should look like:

[image]

### Routes.js

```
Router.route('/', function () {
  this.render('Home');
});

Router.route('/items');
```

### test2.js

```
Template.items.helpers({

});

Template.items.events({

});

Template.Home.helpers({

});

Template.Home.events({

});
```

### test2.html

```
<template name="Home">
    <h1>Simplest template home ever</h1>
</template>

<template name="items">
    <h1>Simplest home items template</h1>
</template>
```

Comment: WOW. My hero! Yes, I was also using Windows. 
Unfortunately, after tearing my hear up so much yesterday, I switched to flow router. Do you think I should change back or stick to it?

Comment: I haven't used flow-router but I've heard some good options about it, as well as negative ones. You should check docs, maybe read on SO and use what suits you better

Comment: I've been trying to find an API for both, but I can't seem to find any, only tutorials.
Edit: Nevermind, found flow router https://github.com/kadirahq/flow-router#api , still gotta find iron router though.

Answer (score 1):

Create a 'lib' folder and place the code inside there.

```
lib/router.js
```

You need to place `{{> yield}}` inside your body tags.

```
<body>
  <h1>Welcome to Meteor!</h1>
    {{> yield}} 
</body>
```

The [iron router guide](http://iron-meteor.github.io/iron-router/) will also show you how to set up a layoutTemplate that can be used to keep a consistent layout across all templates. You will place the {{> yield}} inside the layout template and use the `Router.configure` function to yield other templates inside the layoutTemplate.

Comment: Well, I am trying to go from simple to complicated. If one of the simplest lines (`Router.route('/items');`) doesn't display anything, how can I expect `Router.configure` and `{{> yield}}` to work for me? Nonetheless, I tried it and it also failed to display anything. It still recognizes the route, but it doesn't display any template at all.

Comment: @Yokhen, after viewing your github, you must  create a 'lib' folder at root level and place the router code inside there.

Comment: is there anywhere I can read about this more in detail? I am surprised I haven't read anything about this or missed it entirely.. U_U

Comment: Yeap, no mention of a lib folder in there at all, nonetheless I tried the solution. I added a lib folder, created a "router.js" file and move all the iron:router code there, but nothing changed... U_U I'm trying to show this in the github, but the process for commiting is so complicated...